# Relative Neighbourhood Graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, computational-geometry

Is there some way to efficiently compute the [relative neighbourhood graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_neighborhood_graph) on $n$ Euclidean points in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$?

Though one can simply define

```
MaxDist[x_, y_, point_] := Max[{EuclideanDistance[x, y],
   EuclideanDistance[x, point],
   EuclideanDistance[point, y]}]
```

and then use it on every ${n \choose 3}$ triples of points to determine if, among all possible alternatives, the link is shortest, perhaps a nicer method is available using a matrix of Euclidean distances?

Comment: "a matrix of Euclidean distances" - that is what `DistanceMatrix[]` is for.

Comment: Yes, but how do you compare all triples effectively? You have to do this for multiple tripes for each $n$ points. Perhaps `Nearest`, finding local points to a region, and then testing on those triples for each pair?

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean; it will quickly be combinatorically prohibitive. `Nearest[]` with a radial restriction might be workable, tho.

Comment: The Wikipedia entry gives the definition specifically for $\mathbb{R}^2$. Is this something that people use also in $\mathbb{R}^d, d \ge 3$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM) now has functions for computing a few types of proximity graphs, including the relative neighbourhood graph and β-skeletons.

```
IGRelativeNeighborhoodGraph@RandomPoint[Disk[], 1000]
```

[image]

This is still a work-in-progress and performance optimizations, as well as generalizations, are possible in the future.

Answer (score 8):

## Ad-hoc implementation of Relative Neighborhood Graph (RNG)

Under the heuristic assumption that that each vertex in a `RelativeNeighborhoodGraph` will have at most valence 6, this could be a way to exploit `Nearest` to compute it:

```
ClearAll[RelativeNeighborhoodGraph];
RelativeNeighborhoodGraph[pts_?((MatrixQ[#] && Dimensions[#][[2]] == 2) &)] := 
 Module[{nf, i, j, p, q, edgelengths, edges},
  nf = Nearest[pts -> Automatic];
  i = Join @@ Rest[Transpose[nf[pts, {7, ∞}]]];
  j = Join @@ ConstantArray[Range[Length[pts]], 6];
  edges = DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ Transpose[{i, j}]];
  
  {i, j} = Transpose[edges];
  p = pts[[i]];
  q = pts[[j]];
  edgelengths = Sqrt[Dot[Subtract[p, q]^2, ConstantArray[1., 2]]];
  edges = Pick[
    edges,
    MapThread[
     {x, y, d} \[Function] Length[Intersection[nf[x, {∞, d}], nf[y, {∞, d}]]],
     {p, q, edgelengths + 100 $MachineEpsilon}
     ],
    2
    ];
  Graph[Range[Length[pts]], UndirectedEdge @@@ edges, VertexCoordinates -> pts]
  ]
```

Usage example:

```
SeedRandom[20181008];
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {1000, 2}]
RelativeNeighborhoodGraph[pts]
```

[image]

## Implementation of $\beta$-Skeleton for $\beta \geq 1$

The $2$-Skeleton is precisely the RNG. So we can try to compute this one.

The strategy is the same as above: First sieving out a list of edges that a as-small-as-possible superset of the $\beta$-Skeleton's edge list.
For $\beta \geq 1$, we may exploit that the $\beta$-Skeleton is a subgraph of the edge-graph of the Delaunay triangulation. So we may skip the heuristic sieving argument from above and start from the edges of `DelaunayMesh[pts]`.

```
ClearAll[BetaSkeleton];
BetaSkeleton[
  pts_?((MatrixQ[#] && Dimensions[#][[2]] == 2) &),
  β_ /; β >= 1
  ] := Module[{nf, i, j, p, q, r, edgelengths, edges},
  nf = Nearest[pts -> Automatic];
  edges = 
   MeshCells[DelaunayMesh[pts], 1, "Multicells" -> True][[1, 1]];
  {i, j} = Transpose[edges];
  p = pts[[i]];
  q = pts[[j]];
  r = 0.5 β;
  edgelengths = Sqrt[Dot[Subtract[p, q]^2, ConstantArray[1., 2]]];
  edges = 
   Pick[edges, 
    MapThread[
     {x, y, d} \[Function] Length[
      Intersection[
       nf[x + (r - 1) (x - y), {∞, d}], 
       nf[y + (r - 1) (y - x), {∞, d}]
       ]
      ], 
     {p, q, r (edgelengths + 100 $MachineEpsilon)}
     ],
    2
    ];
  Graph[Range[Length[pts]], UndirectedEdge @@@ edges, VertexCoordinates -> pts]
  ]
```

Examples:

```
BetaSkeleton[pts, 2.0]
```

[image]

```
BetaSkeleton[pts, 2.5]
```

[image]

Comment: I was working on something like `R=RegionIntersection[Disk[{-0.5, 0}, 1], Disk[{0.5, 0}, 1]]` and `RegionMember[R, #] & /@ pts`, since the relative neighbourhood graph is simply the beta skeleton with $\beta=2$, hence the empty lune approach might work, but this is much faster.

Comment: Is there some way to calculate the beta skeleton, of which the RNG is the special case?

Comment: You want the lune-based beta skeletton, right?

Comment: Yes exactly, it is a very nice thing to have given all the special cases it can produce.

Comment: Thank you for this valuable addition.

Comment: You're welcome.